# Ios Run Applescript

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, applescript

Okay the obvious answer to this question is "no" to many but for my problem solvers out there, let's create a workaround. So obviously **cocoa application** and **Xcode OS** can run applecript with **NSapplescript**

- but I want my **iOS Xcode project** to run applescript!

. Does anyone have any ideas. If you don't then you don't have to answer but for my problem solvers, let's try to figure something out.

Comment: It's not a duplicate, the other questions simply says it is impossible, this question want people to apply themselves and help find a workaround. Stack-overflow is getting a little too pretentious.

Comment: It **is** indeed impossible.The entire AppleScript framework is not available on iOS. And even if it was available with all the sandbox restrictions it's useless when you can't talk to other applications.

Comment: If the OP wants to add scriptability to his own iOS app, the JavaScriptCore framework is available on iOS for embedding, and Apple do allow third-party interpreters to be embedded as well, albeit with restrictions. If the OP wants his iOS app to control other iOS apps then he needs to do his own homework on what [very limited](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html) IPC capabilities iOS does provide.

Comment: Also, if the OP is wanting to provide end-user automation support, he should go research the automation apps already available on iOS ([example](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/workflow-powerful-automation/id915249334)) to get an idea of what's already out there and what's feasible and what's not. Oh, and go study Apple's docs on how iOS's sandboxing system and entitlements works, and mind that all apps have to pass the App Store approval process before they can be released, so demanding every entitlement under the sun is a good way to spend the rest of eternity stuck in rejection hell.